# Docker Swarm - Is it possible to restrict network access workers?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

we built a Docker Swarm cluster, over several cloud providers.

Everything works but we have new constraints and need to restrict network communications between the cloud providers.

Is it possible to build a Docker Swarm cluster with "local load balancing"? What I mean by this question is, is it possible to use:
- one cloud provider for Swarm managers, with network access to Swarm workers;
- two cloud providers for Swarm workers, with network access to the Swarm managers, but no network access between these cloud providers?

In that case, would the load balancing still work if someone runs a web request towards one of the workers?

Please find below a drawing of the targeted architecture.

[image: Targeted architecture Docker Swarm]